# Strongswan xl2tpd: Can't connect to local services through vpn

Tags: networking, vpn, l2tp

I have a l2tp vpn server set up and I am trying to access services running on port 9090 via `192.168.67.14`. I can access port 80 but I get connection refused when I try any other port. I have disabled UFW for testing and it's still the same issue.

I can access all the ports via the public IP when the firewall is disabled, and I am getting ping responses from the server as well.

Is there a route I need to add somewhere to pass the vpn traffic? Any help would be appreciated.